# Jquery, Ajax, Post Function, Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

I am a Rails newbie and have a question about posting from ajax to a rails controller, and returning the data to javascript.  I'm pretty unfamiliar with how this actually works, but I've pieced together a working post function from other SOF threads.  Right now, I'm posting the data from a simple button click, and the ajax code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type    : 'POST',
  url     : "http://localhost:3000/fbusers", 
  data    : { tester : { name : 'boom' } },
  success : function(data) {
              alert(data);          
            },  
});
```

Here is the code in the controller, its pretty simple:

```
def create
  @user = User.create( params[:tester] )
end
```

This code works fine to post the data to the create function, which creates (posts?) the entry to the db.  But I would like to return the data in the alert function upon "success."  But right now, the alert just returns object[object].  Can anyone help me pass the post data into the alert function?  If possible, an explanation (or direction to a basic tutorial) would be extremely helpful as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to return the user. In this case i recommend:

```
def create
  @user = User.create( params[:tester] )
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json  { render :json => @user}
  end
end
```

And then just make the ajax call request the json

Comment: @nambrot- thanks a ton for the prompt response.  But at the risk of sounding completely incompetent, I have to ask how exactly do I request the json in the ajax call.  I spent the past 30 minutes trying to google this, and some variation of this snippet is the best I could guess:
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/fbusers", {user})

This didn't work, so I figured I'd just give up and ask.

Comment: Ahh- this worked: 
   alert(data.user.name);
Awesome, thanks again!