# Ruby on rails get mysql information depending on option value

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am wondering how I should go about retrieving information from a mysql database associated with my ruby on rails app. When a user selects a product from the select box, I want to use the value of the selected option to retrieve the product's description and price from the database and then display it in a div. Using the following code:

```
    <select>
        <option value='1'>milk</option>
        <option value='2'>eggs</option>
        <option value='3'>butter</option>
    </select>
    <div id='product_description'></div>
    <div id='product_price'></div>
```

When a user selects eggs for example, the first div would read: 'chicken babies' and the second div would read: '$2.00'.

My select tag is also populated from the database, if that is important to know.

The code to populate the select:

```
    <select>
        <option>Select Add-on</option>
        <% for product in @products %>
        <option value="<%= product.id %>"><%= product.item %></option>
        <% end %>
    </select>
```

I am also using jquery.

I guess I was basically wondering  if I should just use an ajax call or if there was some magic rails way to accomplish the task. If I need to use ajax, can I just do it all from the js.coffee file? I can't figure out how to get the selected options value passed on to another file to select the correct row from the products table.

Comment: You need to do Asynchronous Javascript eXecution (AJAX), can easily be done with jQuery `bind`ing the `Change` event on your `select`, contacting the serveur for the selected `product_id` and responds with a `partial` (or JSON, which is faster but needs to be handle on the client side to "parse" the response and update the view).

Comment: I can't figure out how to contact the server with the correct product id. Is there is a way for ajax to define a variable that equals $(this).options[selectedIndex].attr("value") and then pass that on to my server file?

Comment: You should use `options_for_select` to generate your options (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) combined with a `select_tag` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) to generate the select ;) To get the selected product's id, you can do: `$(this).val()` (jQuery)

Comment: ok thanks for the links. i understand how to acquire the value of the option, but how do i pass it on to another file? for example, in php, you use $_GET to acquire the variable passed. Is there something similiar for a ruby file?

Comment: in controller / view (where you receive a request): `params[:id]` (do `raiser params` to see what it contains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `options_for_select` to generate your options:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/

```
<%= options_for_select([["Dollar", "$"], ["Kroner", "DKK"]]) %>
#generates
<option value="$">Dollar</option>
<option value="DKK">Kroner</option>
```

Combined with a `select_tag` to generate the select:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

```
<% options = "<option>Red</option><option>Green</option><option>Blue</option>".html_safe %>
<%= select_tag "colors", options %>
<div id="product_details"></div>
#generates
<select id="colors" multiple="multiple" name="colors[]">
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Green</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
</select>
<div id="product_details"></div>
```

**In your case:**

```
<% options = options_for_select(@products.map{ |product| [product.item, product.id] }) %>
<%= select_tag('product_search', options) %>

# jQuery
$('#product_search').bind('Click', function(e) {
  var selected_product_id = $(this).val();
  # Then call the Ajax
  $.ajax({url: '/products/details/' + selected_product_id, # URL to contact
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data) {
                     $('#product_details').empty().append(data);
                   }
        });
});
```

- This code will send a request at path `'/products/details/:id'` where `:id` represents the product's id (`ProductsController#details`).

Now you have to code the server side to handle the request, generate the HTML (or responds with JSON, faster but heavier to handle on the client side) and send a response.

- About Ajax: [Jquery, Ajax, Post Function, Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832069/jquery-ajax-post-function-rails)

Comment: alright thanks so much for your help and quick response. i would upvote you, but i guess you need 15 rep. Thanks again.

Comment: i have implemented your code and it is working. Thanks, mate. May your sword stay sharp and your steed be quick.